# How to test form request rules in Laravel 5?

Tags: forms, unit-testing, laravel, testing, request

I created a form request class and defined a bunch of rules. Now I would like to test these rules to see if the behaviour meets our expectations.

How could I write a test to accomplish that?

Many thanks in advance for your answers!

**Update**: more precisely, I would like to write a unit test that would check e.g. if a badly formatted email passes validation or not. The problem is that I don't know how to create a new instance of the Request with fake input in it.

Comment: there is a similar response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978147/unit-test-laravels-formrequest

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Test Laravel's FormRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978147/unit-test-laravels-formrequest)

Comment: Friends, please, make the unit-test properly, after all, it is not only rules you are testing here, the validationData and withValidator functions may be there too. [here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978147/unit-test-laravels-formrequest/55389319#55389319)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have your form request class in the controller function, for example

```
public function store(MyRequest $request)
```

Now create HTML form and try to fill it with different values. If validation fails then you will get messages in session, if it succeeds then you get into the controller function.

When Unit testing then call the url and add the values for testing as array.  Laravel doc says it can be done as

```
$response = $this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! It's not really what I had in mind though :s I think my question was written rather poorly so I updated it. What I am trying to do is write a unit test to check if the validation rules I wrote are correct.

Comment: Improved my answer also

Comment: This seems a little contrived. Shouldn't you focus solely on the Request object and not be dependent on URIs, cookies, etc?

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski though the approach is "valid", it is definitely not best practices. As you said, when unit testing everything apart from the class/function being tested should be mocked/stubbed

Comment: @Juan check this link for a different solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37096837/5058871

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer tests both authorization and validation simultaneously. If you want to test these function separately then you can do this:

test `rules()`:

```php
$attributes = ['aa' => 'asd'];
$request = new MyRequest();
$rules = $request->rules();
$validator = Validator::make($attributes, $rules);
$fails = $validator->fails();
$this->assertEquals(false, $fails);
```

test `authorize()`:

```php
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$this->actingAs($user);
$request = new MyRequest();
$request->setContainer($this->app);
$attributes = ['aa' => 'asd'];
$request->initialize([], $attributes);
$this->app->instance('request', $request);
$authorized = $request->authorize();
$this->assertEquals(true, $authorized);
```

You should create some helper methods in base class to keep the tests DRY.

Comment: Depending on how complex your validation logic is (for instance, if you're assembling the `rules` array via code in your `Request` class), you'll want to assign your `$attributes` array to your custom `Request` class by adding this line after you create your `Request` object: `$request->replace($attributes);`

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding how your import `Validator` in a unit test. It's a facade class, right?

Comment: @Zac: Yeah you are right. You need to import Validator from Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a full example of testing validation:

```php
use App\Http\Requests\PostRequest;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class PostRequestTest extends TestCase
{
    protected function newTestRequest($data = [])
    {
        $request = new PostRequest();

        $request->initialize($data);

        return $request
            ->setContainer($this->app)
            ->setRedirector($this->app->make(Redirector::class));
    }

    public function testValidationFailsWhenEmptyTitleIsGiven()
    {
        $this->expectException(ValidationException::class);

        $this->newTestRequest(['title' => ''])->validateWhenResolved();
    }
}
```

Comment: Steve is always such a baller... exactly what I needed.