# Laravel 5.5 phpunit testing form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, phpunit, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to write some tests for my forms in order to confirm the validators retrieve the expected errors when required.
The form only has 3 fields: `name`, `discount` and `expiration` and the validator looks like this:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name'          => 'required',
    'discount'      => 'required|numeric|between:1,100',
    'expiration'    => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
]);
```

That works fine both when submitting the form and when running the tests with phpunit using the following code:

```
/**
 * Discount must be numeric check
 */
$response = $this->post(route('offer.create'), [
    'name'          => $faker->sentence(4),
    'discount'      => 'asdasd',
    'expiration'    => $faker->dateTimeBetween('+1 days', '+5 months')
]);

// Check errors returned
$response->assertSessionHasErrors(['discount']);
```

Since discount is not numeric it throws the expected error and everybody is happy.

Now, if I want to add a new rule to make sure that the expiration is equal or greater to today I add the `after:yesterday`rule leaving the validator like:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name'          => 'required',
    'discount'      => 'required|numeric|between:1,100',
    'expiration'    => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y|after:yesterday',
]);
```

That works fine when submitting the form. I get the error saying the discount is not numeric, but when testing with phpunit it doesn't get the error as expected:

```
1) Tests\Feature\CreateSpecialOfferTest::testCreateSpecialOffer
Session missing error: expiration
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Why adding this new validation rule to `expiration`generates a false validation in `discount`? Is this a bug in the validator or am I missing something?

Also:

1 - is there a better way to test form validators?

2 - is there an assert that is the opposite of assertSessionHasErrors() to check a certain error is **NOT** been thrown?

Comment: Friends, please, make the unit-test properly, after all, it is not only rules you are testing here, the validationData and withValidator functions may be there too. [here is my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978147/unit-test-laravels-formrequest/55389319#55389319)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit Test Laravel's FormRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978147/unit-test-laravels-formrequest)

Answer (score 0):

If you see this kind of errors in PHPUnit: `Failed asserting that false is true.`, you can add the 'disableExceptionHandling' function to `tests/TestCase.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Exception;
use App\Exceptions\Handler;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    protected function disableExceptionHandling()
    {
        // Disable Laravel's default exception handling
        // and allow exceptions to bubble up the stack
        $this->app->instance(ExceptionHandler::class, new class extends Handler {
            public function __construct() {}
            public function report(Exception $exception) {}
            public function render($request, Exception $exception)
            {
                throw $exception;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In your test you call it like this:

```
    <?php    
    /** @test */
    public function your_test_function()
    {

        $this->disableExceptionHandling();
    }
```

Now, the full output of the error and stacktrace will be shown in the PHPUnit console.

Comment: NOTICE: at later version of Laravel you can use $this->withoutExceptionHandling() without writing any code.